# Como agregar rows a un dataframe ignorando las que ya existan

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente problema...
Resulta que tengo 3 `DataFrame` (c/u es una versión distinta). y necesito hacer un `DataFrame` con operaciones realizadas en base a estos 3 conjuntos de datos.
Explicación de las reglas:

• El `DataFrame` '`resultado`' se va a generar luego de la comparación de la `version2` contra la `version1` .. luego será el turno de comparar la `version3` contra la `version2` y se guardará en el `DataFrame` `'resultado'` .  Mi problema es que no se me ocurre la lógica de guardar en `resultado` después de la primera comparación.. ya que pueden existir productos nuevos, como ocurré en la `version` 2 y 3.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
#creación de dataframes
version1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555'],
              'id_version':['1','1','1','1','1'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda'],
              'precio':[10,22,23,4,15],
              'precio_original':[15,22,30,4,25],
             })

version2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555','666'],
              'id_version':['2','2','2','2','2','2'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda','Falda'],
              'precio':[20,22,25,4,20,27],
              'precio_original':[25,22,30,4,25,40],
             })

version3 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555','666'],
              'id_version':['3','3','3','3','3','3'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda','Falda'],
              'precio':[25,22,27,4,25,29],
              'precio_original':[25,22,30,4,25,49],
             })

#Coincidencia_actual son los productos de la version 2 que se encuentran en la version 1, para poder realizar las operaciones

coincidencia_actual = version2[version2.set_index(['id_sc_producto','tipo']).
                   index.isin(version1.set_index(['id_sc_producto','tipo']).index)]
coincidencia_actual = coincidencia_actual.reset_index(drop=True)

#Coincidencia_anterior son los productos de la version 1 que se encuentran en la version 2, para poder realizar las operaciones

coincidencia_anterior = version1[version1.set_index(['id_sc_producto','tipo']).
                   index.isin(version2.set_index(['id_sc_producto','tipo']).index)]
coincidencia_anterior = coincidencia_anterior.reset_index(drop=True)

#Operaciones en resultado.
resultado['id_sc_producto'] = coincidencia_anterior['id_sc_producto'].copy()
resultado['variacion_precio1'] = coincidencia_actual['precio'] / coincidencia_anterior['precio']
resultado['variacion_precio_original1'] = coincidencia_actual['precio_original'] / coincidencia_anterior['precio_original']
```

Como verán, las operaciones, lo único que hacen es en pocas palabras 'pisar' lo que exista en las columnas. la primera vez esta bien, pero en la segunda comparación lo correcto sería guardarlas en otro `dataframe` y luego hacer un `merge` por ejemplo, pero mi problema es que, si en la segunda comparación hay productos nuevos.. (o sea, `'id_sc_producto'` que no existan en `'resultado'`. no sabría como agregarlos..

la idea sería:
que resultado tenga un input asi:

```
  id_sc_producto v_precio1  v_original1     v_precio2 v_original2
        111      2.000000   1.666667         1.250000   1.000
        222      1.000000   1.000000         1.000000   1.000
        333      1.086957   1.000000         1.080000   1.000
        444      1.000000   1.000000         1.000000   1.000
        555      1.333333   1.000000         1.250000   1.000
        666         0           0            1.074074   1.225
```

como verán el producto 666, esta en 0, en la comparacion 1, porque no se encontraba, pero en la segunda comparación se encontraba.
Espero que se haya entendido lo explicado. gracias por su atención, si hay algo que no quedo claro, leo sus preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad es hacer que `id_sc_producto` sea el índice de todos tus DataFrames y luego hacer uso de `pandas.divide` para dividir las dos columnas entre si por cada pareja de DataFrames usando el índice como eje. Luego puedes usar `pandas.concat` para unir los resultados en un mismo DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd



version1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555'],
              'id_version':['1','1','1','1','1'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda'],
              'precio':[10,22,23,4,15],
              'precio_original':[15,22,30,4,25],
             })

version2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555','666'],
              'id_version':['2','2','2','2','2','2'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda','Falda'],
              'precio':[20,22,25,4,20,27],
              'precio_original':[25,22,30,4,25,40],
             })

version3 = pd.DataFrame({'id_sc_producto':['111','222','333','444','555','666'],
              'id_version':['3','3','3','3','3','3'],
              'tipo':['Remera','Pantalon','Buzo','Remera','Falda','Falda'],
              'precio':[25,22,27,4,25,29],
              'precio_original':[25,22,30,4,25,49],
             })


version1.set_index("id_sc_producto", inplace=True)
version2.set_index("id_sc_producto", inplace=True)
version3.set_index("id_sc_producto", inplace=True)

var1 = version2[['precio', 'precio_original']].divide(version1[['precio', 'precio_original']], axis="index")
var2 = version3[['precio', 'precio_original']].divide(version2[['precio', 'precio_original']], axis="index")
var1.rename(columns={"precio": "v_precio1", 'precio_original': 'v_original1'}, inplace=True)
var2.rename(columns={"precio": "v_precio2", 'precio_original': 'v_original2'}, inplace=True)

resultado = pd.concat([var1, var2], axis=1)
resultado.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Por defecto, `pandas.divide` deja como `NaN` aquellas filas en las que en una columna no hay valor a dividir:

> ```
> >>> div1
>
>                 v_precio1  v_original1
> id_sc_producto                        
> 111              2.000000     1.666667
> 222              1.000000     1.000000
> 333              1.086957     1.000000
> 444              1.000000     1.000000
> 555              1.333333     1.000000
> 666                   NaN          NaN
> ```

esto lo puedes solucionar luego con `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` si de verdad necesitas un 0 en ese caso.

El resultado final es:

> ```
> >>> resultado
>
>                 v_precio1  v_original1  v_precio2  v_original2
> id_sc_producto                                                
> 111              2.000000     1.666667   1.250000        1.000
> 222              1.000000     1.000000   1.000000        1.000
> 333              1.086957     1.000000   1.080000        1.000
> 444              1.000000     1.000000   1.000000        1.000
> 555              1.333333     1.000000   1.250000        1.000
> 666              0.000000     0.000000   1.074074        1.225
> ```